# How to remove the starting header in a MemoryStream and save the rest to a file?

Tags: file, delphi

I currently have a `TMemoryStream` that gets filled via reading a varbinary field, which is originally encoded by UTF8 standard from a MS SQL Server DB table.

The varbinary field contains a header part which needs to be removed before saving the remainder of the stream as a file.

I have successfully pulled out the header information required, which includes the file name, but haven’t
found a solution for then saving the remainder of the stream as a valid file.

The data is initially read into a `TdxMemData` dataset.

```pascal
procedure TBaseDataPump.SaveAttachments(mtblAttachmentInfo: TdxMemData);
var
  AFile: TMemoryStream;
  ANewFile: TStringStream;
  sFullPath: String;
  wsImageBlob, wsHeader, wsBody: WideString;
  iposition: Integer;
begin
  if mtblAttachmentInfo.Active then // TdxMemData filled with data
  begin
    with mtblAttachmentInfo do
    begin
      First;
      while NOT EOF do
      begin
        // Below code works fine to save the file without removing the data
        AFile := TMemoryStream.Create; // Create the memory stream
        TBlobField(FieldByName('ImageBlob')).SaveToStream(AFile);
        // load the file image from the data to the memory strem

        // Get the header content
        ANewFile := TStringStream.Create('');
        TBlobField(FieldByName('ImageBlob')).SaveToStream(ANewFile);
        // read  the filed again to a TStringStream

        wsImageBlob := UTF8ToString(ANewFile.DataString);
        // I can see the data as wide string and can find the header bit and its ending position on the 
        //  its ending position on the  string
        iposition := AnsiPos(#13#13#10, wsImageBlob); // find the header ending position

        // getting the header to another widestring
        wsHeader := AnsiLeftStr(wsImageBlob,position);
        wsHeader := AnsiLeftStr(wsImageBlob,POS(#9,wsHeader)-1);
        wsHeader := StringReplace(wsHeader,'''','',[rfReplaceall]);

        // need to save the stream from the position of the end of header as file
      end;
    end;

  end;
end;
```

Comment: You create the filestream (the destination) set the `Position` of the source stream to where you want to begin the copy, and then use the source stream's `CopyTo` method to copy to the destination. Your code seems overly convoluted, BTW. Why are you creating a `TMemoryStream` only to copy it to a `TStringStream` instead of just going directly from the blob field to the `TStringStream`?

Comment: You cannot remove one starting bit, only one starting byte.

Comment: Hi Ken, Thank you for the reply. I'm using Delphi Tokyo and I could not find a CopyTo method associated with a TMemoryStream, TStringStream , TFileStream or a  TStream. There is a CopyFrom method which gives a 'Stream read error'. As mentioned in comments I used  TMemoryStream to extract the data as TBlobField and save it as file. I used the TStringStream to find the header section(which contains the file name and extension)  and it position. I'm open for any option as long as I can remove the header section and save it as a file. Note that header section length could vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution with the copyfrom method. and its is as follows :

```
      // Create the  TStringStream
      ANewFile := TStringStream.Create('');

      try
        TBlobField(FieldByName('ImageBlob')).SaveToStream(ANewFile);

        // get the blob as a string so we can extract the header information
        wsImageBlob := UTF8ToString(ANewFile.DataString);

        position := AnsiPos(#13#13#10, wsImageBlob);

        if position <> 0 then begin
          // have header information to extract
          position := position + 2;

          wsHeader := AnsiLeftStr(wsImageBlob, position);
          wsHeader := AnsiLeftStr(wsImageBlob, POS(#9, wsHeader) - 1);
          wsHeader := StringReplace(wsHeader, '''', '', [rfReplaceall]);

          sFilePath := sDirectorypath + wsHeader;

          ANewFile.Position := position;     

          AFile := TMemoryStream.Create;
          try
            AFile.CopyFrom(ANewFile, ANewFile.Size - position);

            AFile.SaveToFile(sFilePath);
          finally
            FreeAndNil(AFile);
          end;
        end
      finally
        FreeAndNil(ANewFile);
      end;
```